TCPDUMP file for a ping command execution
Guys,
We have here in TCPDUMP file displayed by Wireshark. It corresponds to a ping from 192.168.30.18 to 192.168.0.100, eg
ping 192.168.0.100

How to understand that ping result is 0% packets loss, but in the TCPDUMP file there are so many "no response found!"
Thanks,
DKay
31  1.677143    192.168.30.18   192.168.0.100   ICMP    78  Echo (ping) request  id=0x6728, seq=33144/30849, ttl=3 (reply in 32)
32  1.677335    192.168.0.100   192.168.30.18   ICMP    78  Echo (ping) reply    id=0x6728, seq=33144/30849, ttl=126 (request in 31)
38  2.010729    192.168.30.18   192.168.0.100   ICMP    78  Echo (ping) request  id=0x6728, seq=33145/31105, ttl=1 (no response found!)
42  2.344119    192.168.30.18   192.168.0.100   ICMP    78  Echo (ping) request  id=0x6728, seq=33146/31361, ttl=2 (no response found!)


the icmp should be delivered from other tools. see that ttl is not the same one
